# Flutter Build Error: Execution failed for task ':sms:verifyReleaseResources',A problem occurred evaluating root project 'firebase_auth'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am creating a simple app that consist of sms retrieving and firebase mobile OTP modules, everything works fine only on app running but could not build apk for output.

Errors:

1. Execution failed for task ':sms:verifyReleaseResources'.
2. A problem occurred evaluating root project 'firebase_auth'.

I have no idea for first error, but the second one is most related to firebase_core plugin. but i have added  it too. let me know where i made mistakes.

I have tried all possible ways that is, cleaning build and reinstalled the plugins noting works for me.

installed plugins:

- sms: ^0.2.4,
- firebase_auth: ^0.19.0,
- firebase_core: ^0.6.0,

[image: error screen shot]

Comment: Try upgrading or downgrading the dependency versions, I think the current dependency versions are not working together.

Comment: tried dependency corrections, but no result